# Event "click" nested in axios response - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

If I have such a structure:

```
methods:
getData: function() {
    Axios({
        url: url,
        type: get
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //getData
        and here I have click event
    })
```

What do I have to do? How do I bind this with `v-on` in a template?

Comment: What is the prop in `v-on` ?

Comment: `and here I have click event` what do you mean by this ? can you be more specific.

Comment: and here I have click event==call method directly?